# I can't Hide Url Parameter,

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

```
@Html.ActionLink("LotNumberDetails", "Index", "LotNumber", new { id = item.lotNUmber }, null)
```

This is my action link in table, when I click on LotNumber ActionLink it generates the following URL:

```
http://servername.com/LotNumber/Index/1111_100868781211
```

The method in controller is as follows:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index(string id)
    {
        var TupleResult = objLotNumberModel.GetLotNumberValuesEnumerable(id);
        return View("Index", TupleResult);
    }
```

Everything is working fine, but when I change ActionLink to Ajax.ActionLink...

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("LotNumber", "Index", "LotNumber", new { id = item.lotNUmber }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST"})
```

and the controller method to...

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string id)
    {
        var TupleResult = objLotNumberModel.GetLotNumberValuesEnumerable(id);
        return View("Index", TupleResult);
    }
```

The method is firing but I can't move to respective page.

My idea is to hide the ID of LotNumber, ie when clicking on ActionLink I Just want to get the URL like "http://servername.com/LotNumber/Index".

Comment: Please stop prefixing every paragraph with `>`. That is for marking up blocks of text with block quotes, which have specific semantic meaning.

Comment: An Ajax action can't return a view the same way that an actionlink can. There is no navigation here. Unless you capture abd use the incoming view in some way, this is a "dead" response. For your purposes, you should continue using html actionlink

Comment: sorry,  i'm new to StackOverflow, please do the needful,

Comment: @DaveA : then How can i hide the URL param, if it is visible any one can edit na?

Comment: one thought is to use javascript redirect. **anchor w empty href, click event and window.location='LotNumber/Index'+@item.lotNUmber.** would that work for you? thats still noticeable on a js debugger, but not so obvious.

Comment: finlally, i left like that only, I did not find any solution so I encrypted the LotNumber using standard Encrption techniques, Thank you all for your valuble time and efforts. :)